# Some word vectors return values of infinite or -infinite

Tags: python, numpy, gensim, word2vec

I trained my word vector like i normally would. I cleaned the text before hand where each line is a sentence with tokens separated by a space

```
class Sentences:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __iter__(self):
        i = 0
        with codecs.open('./data/cleaned_corpus.txt', 'r', 'utf-8') as file:
            for line in file:
                i += 1
                if i % 5000 == 0:
                    print('processed ' + str(i))

                yield line.split()


w2v = Word2Vec(Sentences(), size=100, min_count=10)
w2v.wv.save('model')
```

The issue is that some of the vectors return arrays with values that are numpy infs

```
array([-inf,  inf, -inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf, -inf, -inf,  inf,
    inf, -inf, -inf,  inf,  inf, -inf, -inf,  inf,  inf,  inf, -inf,
    inf,  inf, -inf, -inf, -inf,  inf, -inf,  inf, -inf,  inf,  inf,
   -inf, -inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf, -inf, -inf,
   -inf, -inf,  inf,  inf,  inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf,
   -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf,  inf, -inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf, -inf,
    inf, -inf, -inf, -inf, -inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf, -inf,  inf,
   -inf, -inf,  inf,  inf,  inf,  inf, -inf,  inf, -inf, -inf,  inf,
   -inf, -inf,  inf,  inf,  inf, -inf, -inf,  inf, -inf, -inf, -inf,
    inf], dtype=float32)
```

I've already retrained the vector 3 times, I don't know what's causing this

Comment: I can't reproduce this, so the problem is likely somewhere in your input data. Have you tried it with a different data set? Have you tried with just a small section of your input data set?

Comment: Side note: from your class definition, it looks like you're using Python 3. In that case, you don't really need codecs: `with open('./data/cleaned_corpus.txt', encoding='utf-8') as fp:` will work fine.

Comment: I've not seen this before with gensim. If you enable INFO or DEBUG level logging before training, is there anything fishy in the logging? Is your corpus natural language or something else? What OS and how did you install things like numpy or other support libraries?